# PHP: is it possible to access static methods like this: Object::ChildObject::method()?

Tags: php, javascript, oop

In JS you can access methods in this fashion: ParentObject.ChildObject.ChildObjMethod() -- can same be done in PHP?

Comment: What is `ParentObject`, and what is `ParentObject::ChildObject`? Are either of them classes, or is one or both an instance in its own right?

Comment: well ok, I am wondering if a static class (object) can have a nested static class with certain methods. Typically you can use them like Class::method() but can Class have a nested SubClass that I can access as I described above -- Class::SubClass::SomeMethod() or not?

Comment: No, you can't store a reference to a class in a variable in PHP, or return a class from a method call.  Classes aren't "first class objects" in this sense in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `::` can be used for accessing static class members. But you can also access instantiated childobjects in PHP, using the normal `->` arrow thingy:

```
$parent->child->child_method();
```

See also [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly.  The `::` operator is for invoking **static** methods on a **class**.  So, you could store a reference to an object statically, but then you'd need to invoke the method with a `->` operator.

```
<?php
    class Foo
    {
        static public $bar;

        static public function initStaticMembers()
        {
            self::$bar = new Bar();     
        }
    }

    class Bar
    {
        public function method()
        {
            echo "Hello World\n";
        }

    }

    Foo::initStaticMembers();
    Foo::$bar->method();
```

There's no way to do

```
    Object::ChildObject::method();
```

Method chaining is essentially a shortcut for something like

```
    $o = Object::ChildObject;
    $o::method();
```

The first call is made, and returns or assigns something.  The next method is then called on the thing that's returned.  You can't store a class in a variable with PHP, or return a class from a function.  Therefore, the exact syntax for what you're asking to do is impossible.

That said, method chaining is becoming more popular in PHP.  Syntax like the following

```
    $o = new Baz();
    $o->method()->anotherMethod()->yetAnotherMethod();
    $o->someObjectReference->methodCall()->etc();
```

is becoming common place.  This works because each call or variable reference

```
    $o->method();
    $o->someObjectReference;
```

returns another Object instance, which can then have a method called on it.